# Data not Returned in Deserialized Typed Array from JSON

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, rest, k2

I have this REST api 
I make REST api calls to the Webservice for Instance

```
http://localhost:56295/api/EmployeeDB
```

It returns this Results on PostMan

```
[
    {
        "Fullname": "James Hall",
        "Telephone": "08020772008",
        "gender": "Male",
        "email": "james_hall@onetell.com",
        "date_ofbirth": "1988-05-19T00:00:00",
        "nationalID": "7862367AS",
        "accountnumber": "2093993827",
        "salary": 980000.00
    },
    {
        "Fullname": "Temi Lawson",
        "Telephone": "08038220163",
        "gender": "Female",
        "email": "t_lawson@onetel.com",
        "date_ofbirth": "1987-12-22T00:00:00",
        "nationalID": "7627862SS",
        "accountnumber": "2099302931",
        "salary": 450000.00
    },
    {
        "Fullname": "Qalid R. Osman - Hussein",
        "Telephone": "08022712782",
        "gender": "Male",
        "email": "q.osman@gmail.com",
        "date_ofbirth": "1989-06-02T00:00:00",
        "nationalID": "873909ED",
        "accountnumber": "2002198291",
        "salary": 2328500.00
    },
    {
        "Fullname": "John Snow",
        "Telephone": "08147720192",
        "gender": "Male",
        "email": "john.snow@gmail.com",
        "date_ofbirth": "1985-06-22T00:00:00",
        "nationalID": "JS834788US",
        "accountnumber": "0034773291",
        "salary": 800000.00
    },
    {
        "Fullname": "Tina Martins",
        "Telephone": "08128823781",
        "gender": "Female",
        "email": "tina.martins@loudcom.com",
        "date_ofbirth": "1985-07-25T00:00:00",
        "nationalID": "J834712US",
        "accountnumber": "0331928271",
        "salary": 750500.00
    },
    {
        "Fullname": "Fred Hammond",
        "Telephone": "08026626128",
        "gender": "Male",
        "email": "fred_hammond@loudcom.com",
        "date_ofbirth": "1982-11-25T00:00:00",
        "nationalID": "KL328327D",
        "accountnumber": "0440123920",
        "salary": 2750500.00
    },
    {
        "Fullname": "Jack Holland",
        "Telephone": "08026626128",
        "gender": "Male",
        "email": "Jack_holland@bluebank.com",
        "date_ofbirth": "1982-11-25T00:00:00",
        "nationalID": "KL328327D",
        "accountnumber": "0440123920",
        "salary": 855890.00
    }
]
```

Exactly as i wanted, Now I make another REST api Call using a Parameter for instance, `http://localhost:56295/api/EmployeeDB?accountnumber=0034773291`
And it returns Data for One person

```
[
    {
        "Fullname": "John Snow",
        "Telephone": "08147720192",
        "gender": "Male",
        "email": "john.snow@gmail.com",
        "date_ofbirth": "1985-06-22T00:00:00",
        "nationalID": "JS834788US",
        "accountnumber": "0034773291",
        "salary": 800000.00
    }
]
```

But this is for Postman, Now i built something using a Class Library so I can be able to make REST api calls in an Automation application (K2 SmartForms) After which I would convert into a SmartObject

Which has this source code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace RESTBrowserGET
{
    public class BrowseRESTGet
    {
        public static Object GETRESTInfo(string restUrl, string reqMethod) 
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(restUrl);
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            //var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject[]>(responseString);
            var obj = (JObject)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString, typeof(JObject));
            return obj.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Here comes the main Issue. I want to use the Values retrieved from this Json in an Application, So if for instance, the Class Library makes a REST api call to `http://localhost:56295/api/EmployeeDB?accountnumber=0034773291` It should use the Values gotten from this Json

```
[
    {
        "Fullname": "John Snow",
        "Telephone": "08147720192",
        "gender": "Male",
        "email": "john.snow@gmail.com",
        "date_ofbirth": "1985-06-22T00:00:00",
        "nationalID": "JS834788US",
        "accountnumber": "0034773291",
        "salary": 800000.00
    }
]
```

In My application to view information from the Database, It does not seem to be returning the Values in a **Deserialized Typed Array**, What do I seem to be missing? What Am i not doing correctly?

Comment: "It does not seem to be returning the Values in a Deserialized Typed Array". But you do see the data in "responseString" as you would expect? This is still unclear, unless that is what you meant by "It should use the Values gotten from this Json".

Comment: If I Run the REST api using Postman, i get the output fine and good, but i cannot use the values retrieved from the Database directly from Postman. If I also run it from my created Class library, I also see the output as an Object, Now i want to use the values gotten from the Object in my application, having been called from my class Library. So once it retrieved the data from the REST api as a json string, it deserialises it so I can use it inside the application I am building

Comment: This should explain some other things I mean https://www.enk2besoin.com/2019/09/10/easy-integrations-via-rest/

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio then this might help you. Visual Studio offers a way to create a class for deserializing JSON. Take a look here [How to Parse JSON..](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-paste-json-as-classes-or-xml-as-classes-in-visual-stu/)   :: You can then use that class together with NewtonSoft to deserialization. Best of luck

Comment: What happens if you register the REST interface in K2 and make a SmartObject directly using the REST interface to return the JSON? You need a SWAGGER definition file but you can use the REST calls directly in a Workflow.